# List membership check in Python 3

Tags: python, for-loop, tkinter

I am writing a relatively simple program using Tkinter that is a converter for binary, decimal and hex. I am not using any of the Python built in math functions since I figured this was a good way to get some practice with, not only classes and objects, but Tkinter as well.

I have a method that checks to make sure a binary string is valid by checking if it contains any of the digits `2-9`, which would make it invalid.

To do this I am using an `if` statement embedded within a `for` loop

```
bits = '011101'    #self.input_str.get()
bit_list = [i for i in bits]
ill_bits = ['2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9']

for bit in bit_list:

    if bit in ill_bits:  
        print('yes')
        #self.output_disp.delete(0.0, END)
        #self.output_disp.insert(0.0, "That bit string is invalid")
    else:
        print('no')
        #self.from_binary(self.dec_bttn, self.hex_bttn)`
```

The two `print()` functions are actually not part of the program, they are there as I keep testing different things. The commented out parts are the code that I want to run in the test area of the Tkinter app as results of the validity test.

What is happening here is that the

```
self.output_disp.delete(0.0, END)
self.output_disp.insert(0.0, "That bit string is invalid")
```

is only run if the very last bit in the test is found in both lists. For example a bit string of: `111019` will have `That bit string is invalid` shown in the text area, but `111911` will not. Although both bit strings will print `yes` in the console when the 9 is iterated through, only the one with the 9 in the last spot will run the two lines of code that start `self.output_disp`....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your flow is a little off. You need to break after the first failure, and have the `else` block associated with the `for` instead of the `if`.

Comment: Im not actually sure how you mean to do that, would you mind specifying a bit better, please. An else statement can be asssociated with a for loop, how can one do that?

Comment: Indent it to the same level as the `for` block. In Python, `if` is not the only statement that can have an `else` block.

Comment: I've tried associating the else block (with and without the else) with the 'for' and it doesn't seem to catch any shared membership that way. I think Im not doing something exactly how you were intending it be done with your comment.

Comment: You're probably forgetting to break after the first failure.

Comment: yes, you are right, that is exactly what the issue was. Now that I have it working properly would you mind explaining what was happening in the original way I was doing it that was causing it to act in that way. Its no good learning something unless you can later apply it, and Im not clear as to why my original way wasn't working, nor am I quite clear on the meaning of the else block associated with the 'for' loop. Thanks.

Comment: Your original code catches the error in the middle, but then continues to process the rest of the entry regardless. In order to fix this, the loop must be broken out of. The `else` block in a `for` statement is only executed if the loop is not broken out of. Putting the two behaviors together fixes the problem.

Comment: Ahhh, yeah I get it. One of the things I actually did a few days ago was realize that I had to break the loop and I added that code at one time. I soon abandoned it because I failed to alter the else block to be associated with the 'for' loop, so the break didn't work and made me believe I was not on the right track.  Thanks for taking the time to help me, I learned alot from this post.

Answer (score 2):

You say you're new to Python, so I hope you don't mind a few tips.

There's really no reason to do `[i for i in bits]`.  It's not wrong, but it's not really Pythonic.  If you want a list, which is what this makes, you can just pass the string to the `list` function.  If you want a copy of the string, you can use the slice operator.

```
bit_list = list(bits) # Convert to list
bit_list = bits[:] # Shallow copy of a string
```

The good thing though, is you don't need a copy for this.

---

A really useful function of this is called `any`.  You can check everything at once with it.  Also, integers are easier to work with than strings.  Converting the bits to integers means you don't need that list of strings.

```
bits = '011101'
ill_bits = range(2, 9+1)
if any(int(bit) in ill_bits for bit in bits):
    print('Bad')
else:
    print('Good')
```

Basically it says, if any bit is in both `bits` and `ill_bits` the number is bad.  Otherwise, it's good.

Comment: Hay, thanks. Thats great to know. I didn't know about the 'any' command. Im going to play around with it to familiarize myself. Thanks again

Comment: `any` is a **function**. For future reference, "command" is actually almost never the right word when you're talking about programming

Comment: You can use `ill_bits = "23456789"`and get rid of the `int` call. Or even `if not all(bit in "01" for bit in bits):`

Answer (score 0):

Just to provide an alternate solution, the shortest way to do this is with regular expressions:

```
import re
if re.search('[2-9]', bits):
    print('yes')
else:
    print('no')
```

Comment: Yeah, Thank you, man. I've learned alot from just taking the time to post this one question. I appreciate it. Hope someday I can help one of you guys too.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of the loop, I would do:

```
if [bit for bit in bit_list if bit in ill_bits]:
    raise YourException("illegal bits present")

# now that all bits are legal, fill in the result
```

Here's how it works: when all bits are good, `if bit in ill_bits` is `False` for each `bit` and resulting `[...]` is empty; `bool([]) is False`, thus `if [...]:` is only triggered if you have bad bits.

If you have very large `bit_list`, you can optimize this a little with:

```
if [b for b in set(bit_list) if b in ill_bits]:
    raise ....
```

If your `ill_bits` is potentially large, say if you practise base-999999 arithmetic, then ill_bits should be a set rather than a list.